# Remove Sign In and Forgot Password Text in AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to remove the 'Sign In' and 'Sign in with your email address' and 'Forgot Your Password?' text from an Azure AD B2C login page?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom policy, you can do the following:

1. Customize the [string ID's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids). You must have [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization) set up in your [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition). You need to find the string ID that matches the default text that you see. For example:

**button_signin -> "Sign in"**

**local_intro_generic   -> "Sign in with your {0}"**

You can just change it to empty string as follows:

***button_signin -> ""***

However, this ID may be slightly different depending on which [content definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions) you are using. Also, you may still see an empty line.

2. A better solution is to use [custom HTML templates, CSS and JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). You can then use your CSS or JavaScript to hide any HTML element. This solution is possible even if you are not using custom policies. You can also do this solution together with your custom policies.

In a custom policy, [you can hide **"Forgot your password?"**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) as follows:

```
<Metadata>
 <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">None</Item>
</Metadata>
```

If you are not using a custom policy, again, you can just hide it with CSS and/or JavaScript.